# Problem with deleting pictures in range with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to delete all pictures what are in defined range. Originaly I tried to use:

```
Dim OBR as Picture
For Each OBR In ActiveSheet.Pictures
If Not Intersect(OBR.TopLeftCell, Range("B2:B7")) Is Nothing Then
OBR.Delete
End If
Next OBR
```

Unfortunately it is not working - code stops on `For Each OBR In ActiveSheet.Pictures` with no hint why.

I also tried code I found here on forum:

```
    Dim xPicRg As Range
    Dim xpic As Picture
    Dim xRg As Range
    
    Set xRg = Range("B2:B7")
    For Each xpic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
        Set xPicRg = Range(xpic.TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & xpic.BottomRightCell.Address)
        If Not Intersect(xRg, xPicRg) Is Nothing Then xpic.Delete
    Next
```

Same issue. On sheet there are 8 pictures (and cca 10 shapes), which only 6 pictures are supposed to be deleted.  `ActiveSheet.Pictures.count` gives me right value 8. When it was not working with range I also tried something like this:

```
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Pictures.count

    If Not ActiveSheet.Pictures(i).Name = ob100 Or ActiveSheet.Pictures(i).Name = ob125 Then
    ActiveSheet.Pictures(i).Delete
    Else
    End If
Next i
```

But it is not working also, so Im very stucked. Please any help why the first macro is not working?

The ob100 and ob125 what excel counts as pictures are acctually checkboxes and the rest are inserted pictures.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Look at all the `Shapes` on the sheet and check if `OBR.Type = msoPicture`

Comment: You cannot use For Each to delete item from a collection.  Imagine the collection is a stack of plates.  You delete plate 3 by removing it from the collection, but then all the plates movedown 1 so that what was Plate 4 is now Plate 3.  If I now tell you to delete Plate 4, you will remove the plate that is 4th in the stack, but that was Plate 5 before you removed Plate 3.  So for collections you always have to use count and count down in steps of -1. e.g. 'For i = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Count To 1 Step -1'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try code below.  You'll probably need to change the sheet name in the code.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim OBR As Shape
    For Each OBR In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes
        If OBR.Type = msoPicture Then
            If Not Intersect(OBR.TopLeftCell, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B7")) Is Nothing Then
                OBR.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next OBR

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code won't delete correctly because you are deleting from a collection.  This is a common newbie mistake in VBA.

Comment: @freeflow I kind of take offense to the newbie statement after 25 years in Excel, but whatever floats your boat.  I've never had that problem with collections of this kind.  Removing rows from a sheet yes, but a collection of shapes... no.  If I was to remove the check for location it should leave every other shape?  i.e. Delete Shape 1, Shape 2 now becomes Shape 1, delete Shape 2 and that deletes Shape 3 which has moved up a position.... so how come it deletes all shapes?  Anything I could read up on?

Comment: Rather than being offended explain why I'm wrong, Then whenever a VBA newbie reads these posts they will end up being better educated.  And with a bit of luck, so will I.

Comment: Thank you!! Thecode you posted works perfectly!! Thank you. But still I have no idea why my code didnt work, when one of the solutions I posted is literaly on overy other forum posted as solution.

Comment: @freeflow.  Not offended by the query, just the newbie statement - reminds me of playing COD when children shout NOOB for no reason.  I'm not saying you're wrong, just that I've never found that problem when deleting from collections of objects, just when deleting rows from a sheet - which is exactly as you explain in your comment on the original question.

Comment: I did a little bit of testing just now printing the shape name & deleting it - it didn't miss any shapes as it looped through.  What I don't understand though is I copied the same shape 6 times. Three were called "Picture x" and two were called "Graphic x".  Now I'm confused as to why it changed the name.

Comment: @Vecernice - sorry, I don't know.  Intellisense doesn't even give me `Picture` as an option with `Dim shp As...`, but your code does work as expected when I try it.